# How to get a group of names all with the same first letter from an alphabetically sorted list?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, search

I was wondering what is the best way to get a group of names given the first letter.  The present application I am working in is in javascript, but I had a similar problem in another language sometimes ago.  One idea I have thought of would be to do a binary search for the end of the names from a particular letter and then do another binary search for the beginning.  Another idea was to take the ratio of of the distance of the given letter from the beginning and applying that ratio to find where to start the search.  For example if the letter was 'e' then I would start start a quarter of the way through the list, and do some kind of search to see how close I am to the letter I need.  The program will be working with several hundred names so I really didn't want to just do a for loop and search the whole thing.  Also, I am interested what kind of algorithms for this are out there?

Comment: Several hundred should not be a problem to loop through normally, I have worked with rebuilding a flat list of over 1000 items in javascript into a tree structure based on parentid, itemid properties per line and the tree was done in well under ½ second.

Comment: Why won't binary search work?

Comment: Beware: A binary search on a single letter key will not guarantee to position you on any particular key starting with that letter, therefore where ever you hit you will need to search forward and backward to find the entries with that letter.

Comment: have a look at these structures http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree.  both are good solutions for auto-complete. Normally I would say more but currently I have to run!  :-)

Comment: @Software Monkey Binary search for the string "e" will get you to the first word starting with 'e' -- no need to for a linear search after that. To find all words starting with 'e', do a binary search for "e" and for "f". The latter search can be made faster by setting the bounds to the highest entry seen from the first search that is >= "f" and the lowest entry seen from the first search that is <= "f".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your approaches have their advantages and disadvantages. Binary search gives *exactly* O(log(N)) complexity, and your second method will give *approximately* O(log(N)) with some advantage for uniform distribution of names and possibly disadvantage for another type of distribution. What is better is up to your needs.

One big improvement I can propose is **to index character positions while creating names list**. Make simple hash map with first letters as keys and start positions as values. It will take O(N), but only once, and then you will get exact position for each letter in a constant time. For JavaScript you can do it, for example, while loading data to the page, when you walk trough the list anyway.

Comment: ffriend could you please tell me what hash function would you use to construct your hash table.Can't we use a counting sort based approach.pls could you see my answer and tell me if anything is wrong in my solution.

Comment: Your solution is correct and almost identical to mine. The only difference is that you use array and I propose hash function, but in fact both these data structures represent same idea - `Map`, that connects keys to values. In your case keys are positions in array, but in JavaScript (which is primary language for the author) there are no real arrays, arrays are just same hash maps with numbers as keys. So, where you use `array[code(letter) - 65]` I use just `array[letter]` (or even `array.letter`). For other languages you can indeed use an array or tree or any other `map`-like structure.

Comment: @Algorithmist: also consider using `@` before name of user you want to talk - SO will notify that user in this case.

Comment: ok @ffriend, in the future i would not make this mistake again.

Answer (score 1):

Guys I think we could use an approach similar to count sort.We could create an array of size 26 .This array would not be an normal array but would be an array of pointers to linked list which has the following structure.

Struct node
{
 char *ptr ;
struct node *next;
};

struct node * names[26];    //Our array.

Now we would scan the list in O(n) time and corresponding to the first character we could subtract 65 (if ASCII value of letter is in the range 65 - 90).Guys i am subtracting 65 so as to fix the letter in 26 sized array.
At each location we could create a linked list and can store the corresponding words in that location.

Now suppose if we want to find all letters that begin with D we could directly do to array location 3(No need to apply hash function again) and then traverse linked list created till null is reached.

And what i think space complexity required in hashing would be same as that of above but hashing would also involve computing hash function every time when we want to insert or search for words beginning with same letter.

Comment: Here O(n) means n is the number of words in the input list.This is because we could increase the pointer by length of current word to point it to next word.

Answer (score 0):

If the plan is to do something with the names (as opposed to just find out how many there are), then it will be necessary to scan the names that fit the criteria of matching the first letter.  If so, then it seems that a binary search for the first name in the entire set is the fastest method.  The "do something" part would involve scanning the names starting from the location found by the binary search.  When a name is read that no longer starts with the given letter, you are done.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an unsorted set of filenames then I would propose following algorithm:

1) Create two variables: **1)** currently found first letter (I will call it *currentLetter*) **2)** list of filenames which start with this letter  (*currentFilenames*)
2) `firstLetter = null`
  `currentFilenames = []` - empty list or array
3) Iterate over filenames. If current filenames starts with `currentLetter` then add this filename to the `currentFilenames`. If it starts with letter which goes before `currentLetter`  then assign `currentLetter` to the first letter of new filename and create a new `currentFilenames` list which consists only of one current filename.

With such an algorithm you will have at the end a letter which goes first in the alphabet and list of files starting from that letter.

Sample code (tried to write in Javascript but do not blame if I wrote anything wrong):

```
function GetFirstLetterAndFilenames(allFilenames) {
    var currentLetter = null;
    var currentFilenames = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < allFilenames.length ; i++) {
        var thisLetter = allFilenames[i][0];
        if (currentLetter == null || thisLetter < currentLetter) {
            currentLetter = thisLetter;
            currentFilenames = [allFilenames[i]];
        } else if (currentLetter == thisLetter) {
            currentFilenames.push(allFilenames[i]); 
        }
    }

    return new {lowestLetter = currentLetter, filenames = currentFilenames};
}
```

Comment: Look at the title - list *is* already alphabetically sorted ;)

Answer (score 0):

Names have a funny way of not distributing themselves evenly over the alphabet, so you're probably not going to win by as much as you'd hope by predicting where to look.

But a really easy way to cut your search down by an average of two steps is as follows: if the letter is from `a` to `m`, binary search for the next letter.  Then binary search from the beginning of the list *only to the position you just found for the next letter*.  If the letter is from `n` to `z`, binary search for it.  Then, again, only search the portion of the list after what you just found.

Is this worth saving two steps?  Dunno.  It's pretty easy to implement, but then again, two steps don't take very long.  (Correctly guessing the letter would save you maybe 4 steps at best.)

Another possibility is to have bins for each letter to begin with.  It starts out already sorted, and if you have to re-sort, you only have to sort within one letter, not the whole list.  The downside is that if you need to manipulate the whole list frequently, you have to glue all the bins together.